# JSON.stringify in Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, internet-explorer, ecmascript-6

I have 1 line of code that crashes my entire JavaScript file in Explorer 11, but working perfectly in google chrome  49.0.2623. 
I 'Export' javascript objects through AJAX with the following code.

In Chrome:

```
function AjajPostComponentLists()

{

  var myFileContent = new Uint8Array();

   var aList1 = {FixedItems:1, List:["None", "Relay #1", "Relay #2"]};
   var aList2 = {FixedItems:1, List:["None", "Input #1", "Input #2", "Input #3", "Input #4", "Input #5"]};
   var aList3 = {FixedItems:1, List:["None", "Door #1", "Door #2"]};

   // ... (I won't list them all)

   myFileContent = JSON.stringify({aList1, aList2, aList3});

   // ...
}
```

The result will look like this:

```
{"aList1":{"FixedItems":1,"List":["None","Relay #1","Relay #2"]},"aList2":{"FixedItems":1,"List":["None","Input #1","Input #2","Input #3","Input #4","Input #5"]},"aList3":{"FixedItems":1,"List":["None","Door #1","Door #2"]}}
```

Explorer 11 complains:

> SCRIPT1003: ':' attendu (awaited i guess, my explorer is in french)

anyways the error refers to the ternary operator which is, obviously unrelated.

I tried to put square brackets instead of curly braces and it 'pass' except i loose a lot in the process (object names for instance).

Any clue why this would go fine on Chrome but not IE ?

Thanks

Comment: `Expected ':'`. IE11 does not support ES6

Comment: IE doesn't support [shorthands](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) in object literals, added by ES6. You'll need to provide a key with each value –– `{ aList1: aList1, aList2: aList2, ... }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that [IE doesn't support](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-object_literal_extensions) ES6 object literal extensions ie:

```
var text = 'some text';
var obj = { text };
console.log(obj); // { text: 'some text' }
```

To fix the issue, you'll have to declare the property name for the corresponding variable:

```
myFileContent = JSON.stringify({
    aList1: aList1,
    aList2: aList2,
    aList3: aList3
});
```

But to make that easier (because you have a lot of `aListX` variables) let's do this:

```
// Instead of aList1 = x, aList2 = y, let's make an array of lists
var aList = [];
aList.push({FixedItems:1, List:["None", "Relay #1", "Relay #2"]});
aList.push({FixedItems:1, List:["None", "Input #1", "Input #2", "Input #3", "Input #4", "Input #5"]});
aList.push({FixedItems:1, List:["None", "Door #1", "Door #2"]});

// ...

var aListObj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < aList.length; i++) {
    aListObj['aList' + (i + 1)] = aList[i];
}

myFileContent = JSON.stringify(aListObj);
```

voila! Now you don't have to type out every single one in your final object, just loop over the array. The output will be as desired.

Comment: Interesting... I am getting on this right away ! Thanxs :)

Comment: In your above exemple, would there be a way to create objects statically (without any push code) ? Theses are globals and the server i use has no 'onApplicationStart', no 'Global.asa' etc. so they would need to be created like this (the syntax is not good):

var aEditbleObjects =
[
    aRelayList : {FixedItems:1, List:["None", "Relay #1", "Relay #2"]};
    aInputList : {FixedItems:1, List:["None", "Input #1", "Input #2", "Input #3", "Input #4", "Input #5"]};
    aDoorList : {FixedItems:1, List:["None", "Door #1", "Door #2"]};
  ...
];

Comment: Yeah, though your syntax there isn't valid. If `aEditbleObjects` is an array then you would get rid of all the push stuff and just loop over `aEditbleObjects`. If `aEditbleObjects` is an object, then you'd just JSON.stringify it for `myFileContent`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanxs for your feedback, this has improoved considerably my code **plus** making IE work again. I summarize here:

1. Creating a global array of object:

var aEditableObjects =
{
    Relay : {FixedItems:1, List:["None", "Relay #1", "Relay #2"]},
    Input : {FixedItems:1, List:["None", "Input #1", "Input #2", "Input #3", "Input #4", "Input #5"]},
    Door : {FixedItems:1, List:["None", "Door #1", "Door #2"]}
};

2. Stringify it, send it through AJAX

   myFileContent = JSON.stringify(aEditableObjects);

   myFileContent = encodeURI(myFileContent); // Facultative, For special chars
3. Salvage it again through AJAX

   try{aEditableObjects = JSON.parse(decodeURI(xmlhttp.responseText));}catch(e){AjajError("AjajGetComponentLists");}

Answer (score -1):

Try `JSON.stringify([aList1, aList2, aList3]);` reference [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: Yes as i mentionned in my question, i tried the square brackets but i loose the array names in the process...